# Loading navigation controllers after another view

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to load a navigation controller after a home page, so on the home page I have an action that is triggered when a icon is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)showContact:(id)sender {

    ContactViewController *Contactcontroller = [[[ContactViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    Contactcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:Contactcontroller animated:YES];

}
```

This then loads the navigation controller view, but in interface builder I can't set the view as navigation controller, so have added a view along side the nav controller, but how would I load this into the view?

Sorry if newbie question...

Comment: You should not use uppercase for variable names in Obj-C, use camelCase, i.e. contactController instead of Contactcontroller. Regarding your question: Is ContactViewController a navigation controller? What view do you want to load into which other view?

Comment: I have a main view which I the want to load a new view ContactViewController which does hold a navigation controller yes. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think what is comes down to is, my app started of as a utility app, then a few views in I want to create a navigation controller. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new project and had it all as a navigation based app, this way on the home screen I managed to hide the Navigation Controller, and then pushed the new views in.
This seemed the easiest way to achieve what I wanted.